# Spring Cloud: using AWS Parameter Store only with certain profiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

I am integrating my application with AWS parameter store. For local development which may have no access to AWS I need to disable fetching property values from AWS and use values from application.yml. The issue seems to be not application.yml, but the dependencies: as soon as AWS starter appears in POM, AWS integration is being initialized: Spring is trying to use AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator. I guess what I need to do is to force my application to use Spring's property source locator regardless of AWS jar being on the class path.  Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For parameter store it is quite easy:  AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration bean is conditional on property *aws.paramstore.enabled*. Creating *aws.paramstore.enabled* environment variable and setting its value to *false* will disable AWS parameter store.

I also tried disabling AWS secrets manager and setting *aws.secretsmanager.enabled* to *false* is not sufficient. To fully disable it I had to disable auto configuration for few classes:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration;

@Configuration
@Profile("local")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class, ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration.class,
        ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration.class, ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class,
        MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class })
public class LocalScanConfig {
}
```